# Topological sort variant

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, topological-sort

Given a list known to be topological sort. It just contains names of nodes. edges between nodes in the list is not given. Suppose a new node is given, with edges to/from the nodes in the list, how to insert the new node into the topological sort?

Comment: I am thinking of solving it by assuming the worst case scenario graph for list given. Suppose list is [P1,P2,P3]. This can viewed as graph P1->P2->P3. Now this will be just a top-sort. But I think there is a much more optimized solution for this.

Comment: I don't believe it is, in general, possible.

Comment: Even with some additional exceptions like from edges are of lower priority than to edges?

Comment: Consider the graphs containing P1, P2, P3. The first graph contains P1->P2 and the second one P2->P3. For both graphs, P1,P2,P3 is a legitimate ordering. Now we add P4 with P3->P4 and P4->P1. Where does P2 go in the result?

Comment: I am not really sure why there are two graph. At any point there is only one graph

Comment: If [P1,P2,P3] is the top-sort given with P3->P4 and P4->P1, there will be a cycle by my solution. In other words in worst case there is a cycle. For practical scenario, I am just breaking the cycle with that additional exception I mentioned.

Comment: My use case just warrants me to get correct top-sort in most of the situation not all the cases.

Comment: I posited two graphs to show that there is not enough information to give a solution. Both graphs have the same topo sort when you start, and that is all the information you have. Now you add P4, but the end result is different for the two graphs. So the information you had available is not sufficient to find the solution. (And neither graph is cyclic with the addition of P4.)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the new node between the last "from" node and the first "to" node. If there is no cycle index of the last "from" node will be smaller than index of the first "to" node so you can add the new node between them.